# Mixing C and C++ code yields unexpected behavior in GCC

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I use legacy C-Code in my current C++ project by including external headers:

```
extern "C" {
# include "ANN/ANN_4t70P1.h"
# include "ANN/ANN_4t70P2.h"
# include "ANN/ANN_4t70P3.h"
# include "ANN/ANN_4t70P4.h"
}
```

The header files look like this:

```
extern int ANN_4t70P1(float *in, float *out, int init);

static struct {
  int NoOfInput;    /* Number of Input Units  */
  int NoOfOutput;   /* Number of Output Units */
  int(* propFunc)(float *, float*, int);
} ANN_4t70P1REC = {8,3,ANN_4t70P1};
```

The C-Code is created by an ancient batch-file and cannot be compiled using C++ compilers. Nevertheless, this implementation works fine for Windows and Mac OS. However, when I compile the code using gcc and g++ on Linux and run the application, ANN_4t70P1REC returns incorrect values.

Are there any special linker flags that I missed out when linking the project?

Thanks!

Comment: ANN_4t70P1REC is an instance of a struct.  What do you mean specifically when you say it "returns incorrect values"?

Comment: Maybe you need it all to be compiled in 32 bit? Newer machines could be installed as 64 bit so you might need to add the `-m32` compiler flag

Comment: Sorry. Of course I mean the function propFunc within the instance ANN_4t70P1REC that returns unexpected results.
The values do not seem to be random values or unallocated memory, but they are completely different from the values that I get with XCode or VC++.

Comment: Make a small C-only test program, and check if that returns correct values.

Comment: You don't have something odd like storing *propFunc in an int somewhere?  On 64-bit machines, the pointer will be 8 bytes, not 4.  As suggested, try `-m32` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: There may be a side effect from the use of float versus using double in your function calls.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/41712/

Comment: Hmmm...  When I first learned C, I seem to recall `int` being 16-bits long.  How ancient is this legacy code?  What happens if you use `short` wherever `int` was used?

Comment: @paddy: The size of `int` is guaranteed to be *at least* 16 bits, but it can be larger; 32 bits is typical these days. It depends on the implementation. There has never been a language requirement that `int` is exactly 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by:

> The C-Code is created by an ancient batch-file and cannot be compiled
>   using C++ compilers

Are you linking using object files generated by different compilers?
If so, try to inspect your object files with:

```
readelf -h <objectname>
```

Check if there is a different ABI. If the code is generated by a very old GCC <3.3/3.4 you can have problems linking with newer versions.

Are you sure you don't have any warnings during the link?